# Using lazy variable vs. Initializing - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm making an app with thousands of inputs.

I have a model class like this

```
class Waterz {

var id: String = ""
var entitle: String? = nil
var artitle: String? = nil
var date: [String]? = nil
var frequency: [daysOfWeek]? = nil
var subMenus: Array<Waterz>? = nil
var location: String? = nil
var audio: [reciterNames]? = nil
var menuIcon: String? = nil

init() {
}

convenience init(id: String, entitle: String, artitle: String, date: [String]?, frequency: [daysOfWeek]?, location: String?, audio: [reciterNames]?) {
    self.init()
    self.id = id
    self.entitle = entitle
    self.artitle = artitle
    self.date = date
    self.frequency = frequency
    self.location = location
    self.audio = audio
}

}
```

And then I have my filling-up class. My filling up class has thousands of variables, so I wanted to see if I should use lazy vars or declare each variable, then initialize it in the `init()` like this

```
class Database {
     var duaKumayl: Waterz

     init() {
          duaKumayl = .init(...)
     }
}
```

Or should I use lazy vars? Using my current method of declaring then initializing will take forever because I have thousands of variables.

Comment: Why do you need thousands of variables? There may well be a better way to do this.

Comment: So, if initializing takes forever, use lazy and see if it fixes the issue. I dont undestand the question here. Or if that does not work either, think about concurrency.

Comment: You can use `struct` instead of `class`. The automatic memberwise initializer of it will help you with that a lot.

Comment: Hi chris, thanks for your response. What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: Brother Mojtaba, thank you for your response. I’m working on a dua app and its mostly completed. Would you mind if I contact you to ask you a few questions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do pagination within app , if you have thousands of variables . This will reduce the show up time for the data you are presenting in UI.

In such cases as i mentioned above , you should use initialization . But if your evaluation of data takes too long use lazy variables.